# Concatenate unique value separated by comma in two string in C++

Tags: c++

```
            CString s;
            int res = 0;
            char *existing;
            char *current;
            existing = strtok(urls, ",");
            current = strtok(storedurls, ",");
            while (existing != NULL)
            {
                while (current != NULL)
                {
                    res = strcmp(existing, current);
                    if (res == 0) continue;
                    s.Append(current);
                    current = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    if (current != NULL) s.Append(",");
                }
                existing = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }

            strcat(urls, s);
```

> We have a string of storedurl L("url1,url2,url3") and urls L("url3,url5") and I want to store the unique urls from both string and get a single output as L("url1,url2,url3,url5")

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: This lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying to implement the described functionality, the symptoms of failure, if any and the steps you did to find the error, like debugging, instrumentation, experiments. And just in case this is homework-related, please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            DWORD res = 0;
            CString existingUrls = urls;
            CString curUrls;
            CString curItemInExitingUrl;
            CString curItemInCurUrl;
            CString urlsToAdd;
            while (!existingUrls.IsEmpty()) {
                CWinLogFile::GetTok(existingUrls, _T(","), curItemInExitingUrl);
                
                curUrls = src.urls;
                while (!curUrls.IsEmpty()) {
                    CWinLogFile::GetTok(curUrls, _T(","), curItemInCurUrl);
                    if (curItemInExitingUrl.Compare(curItemInCurUrl)==0)
                    {
                        res = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (res == 0)
                {
                    urlsToAdd.Append(curItemInExitingUrl);
                    urlsToAdd.AppendChar(',');
                }
                else 
                    res = 0;
            }
            urlsToAdd.Append(src.urls);
```

Found the solution for my posted question. Where urls & src.urls are two comma separated values of urls. Thanks.

Comment: This locks you into Windows. Prefer cross-platform solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Stop using C-style string functions in C++ and get acquainted with the C++ Standard Library.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const& src, char delim = ',')
{
    std::vector<std::string> dst;
    std::stringstream ss{ src };
    std::string tmp;
    while (std::getline(ss, tmp, delim))
        dst.push_back(tmp);
    return dst;

}

int main()
{
    std::string foo{ "url1,url2,url4" };
    std::string bar{ "url2,url3,url5" };

    auto foo_urls{ split(foo) };
    auto bar_urls{ split(bar) };

    std::vector<std::string> unique_urls{ foo_urls.begin(), foo_urls.end() };
    unique_urls.reserve(foo_urls.size() + bar_urls.size());

    unique_urls.insert(unique_urls.end(), bar_urls.begin(), bar_urls.end());
    std::sort(unique_urls.begin(), unique_urls.end());
    unique_urls.erase(std::unique(unique_urls.begin(), unique_urls.end()), unique_urls.end());

    for (auto const& url : unique_urls)
        std::cout << url << '\n';
}
```